How to make all targets in the Makefile depend on a specific file?
Here in make I want to make all targets in the whole Makefile depend on a specific file. (That specific file is Makefile in fact, because that's where I have all my formulas. But that's beside the point.)
Here we see I have, like some nincompoop, painstakingly added it to each target,
$ grep Y Makefile
Y = Makefile
h32540000_zong.csv: $Y; $L | perl -pwle 'BEGIN{$$b=3; $$start=5;};$w; s/@\s+/\n/g;' > $@
h32540000_heng.csv: $Y; $L | perl -pwle \
h32540001_zong.csv: $Y; $L | perl -pwle 'BEGIN{$$start=8;};$w;$(\
h32540001_wall_zong.csv: $Y; $L | perl -wple \
h32540001_heng.csv: $Y; $L | perl -pwle \
h32540001_wall_heng.csv: $Y; $L | perl -pwle \

Is there some smarter way?
Is there some
.ALL_TARGETS: Makefile #or,
%: Makefile

etc. notation I could use to achieve the same effect?
Or maybe just have it operate on all targets that match a specific pattern?
I was thinking of using the % notation, but alas that would reassign the command list of how to make each target...

I honestly feel bad about saying this, because I think you've considered this before, and that's where "that's besides the point" comes from, in your answer, but: This really sounds like you're doing things in your Makefile that should instead be done in an external file that the files that use the formulas actually depend on. I think, honestly, that the easiest way here is to just manually run make with --always-make, whenever you change the Makefile. Having the Makefile be part of the things definining how your software built with make works is just antithetical, in my humble opinion,

and hence make doesn't make great provisions for treating the Makefile itself as part of the software sources.

This is beside the point but using % wouldn’t redefine other rules/recipes (“reassign the command list”), it would be ignored for defined rules.

At least with GNU Make you can add prerequisites by adding a rule without a recipe:
$(wildcard *): Makefile

foo:
    touch foo

bar:
    touch bar

This ensures that all existing files are considered to have Makefile as a prerequisite. This has the side-effect of warning about the circular dependency of Makefile on itself, but I’m not sure there’s a way around that.
In your case you can avoid this by limiting the wildcard:
$(wildcard *.csv): Makefile
h32540000_zong.csv: ; $L | perl -pwle 'BEGIN{$$b=3; $$start=5;};$w; s/@\s+/\n/g;' > $@
h32540000_heng.csv: ; $L | perl -pwle \
h32540001_zong.csv: ; $L | perl -pwle 'BEGIN{$$start=8;};$w;$(\
h32540001_wall_zong.csv: ; $L | perl -wple \
h32540001_heng.csv: ; $L | perl -pwle \
h32540001_wall_heng.csv: ; $L | perl -pwle \

etc.
